# AJAX Product Filters for WooCommerce работает только один фильтр одновременно

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Использую WoordPress + WooCommerce + [AJAX Product Filters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/) (Для подгрузки меню)

Ситуация такая - у меня есть меню, где я могу выбрать несколько видов продукции. Когда выбираю один (допустим мясо свинины), то мне выдает список соответствующих товаров. НО если я выбираю два пункта одновременно - ничего не загружается.

В коде я использую следующую конструкцию:

```
<li>
<a>
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[br_filters attribute=pa_ostrich_meat type=checkbox title=""]'); ?>
</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
        <?php echo do_shortcode( '[br_filters attribute=pa_ostrich_deli type=checkbox title=""]'); ?>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
        <?php echo do_shortcode( '[br_filters attribute=pa_ostrich_half_stuff type=checkbox title=""]'); ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, саму проблему по ссылке https://kalymera.ru/

Зарание спасибо.

Comment: Не надо удалять вопросы. Надо было поправить тот, где я давал комментарий.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Как быть теперь? (Извините)

Comment: Не пойму, а как может что-то загружаться, если я выбрал свинину и говядину одновременно? У вас продукт имеет атрибуты, как я вижу. И этот атрибут либо свинина, либо говядина.

Comment: А можно условие И поменять на ИЛИ?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в опции шорткода оператор OR, как описано на главной странице плагина:

SHORTCODE OPTIONS:

- attribute(required) – product attribute, eg price or length. Don’t forget that woocommerce adding pa_ suffix for created attributes. So if you create new attribute jump its name is pa_jump
- type(required) –  checkbox, radio, slider or select
- operator – OR or AND
- title – whatever you want to see as title. Can be empty
- product_cat – parent category id
- cat_propagation – should we propagate this filter to child categories? set 1 to turn this on
- height – max filter box height. When height is met scroll will be added
- scroll_theme – pretty clear name, scroll theme. Will be used if height is set and real height of box is more

Должно быть так:

```
[br_filters attribute=pa_ostrich_meat type=checkbox title="" operator="OR"]
```

Comment: К сожалению это не помогает. В верстке OR генерировалось в data атрибутах по стандарту.

Comment: Если мы посмотрим на демо http://woocommerce-products-filter.berocket.com/shop/filters/color/orange-green/, то увидим, что OR работает только с одним атрибутом. Например, с цветом, как по ссылке - atribute=color, value=orange or green. Посмотрите в консоли браузера, поймете, о чем я. Попробуйте для теста поставить кролику и баранине один новый атрибут, скажем, meat. А вот значения этого атрибута задать как meat_rabbit и meat_ram

Comment: Т.е. У каждого пункта должен быть общий атрибут?

Comment: Ну да, общий атрибут - мясо. А значения его разные. Как цвета в демо